# Cannot read property 'values' of undefined in angular email editor

Tags: angular

> Getting this error when I try to load data

HTML

```
<button (click)="exportHtml()">Export</button>
<button (click)="loadDesign()">Import</button>
<email-editor></email-editor>
```

Typescript

```
  export class EmailComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any
  @ViewChild(EmailEditorComponent) private emailEditor: EmailEditorComponent;
  constructor(private emailService: EmailService) { }

  exportHtml() {
    this.emailEditor.exportHtml((data: { chunks: any, design: any, html: any }) => {
      this.data = data
    })
  }

  loadDesign() {
   console.log(this.data)
   this.emailEditor.loadDesign(this.data)
  }
}
```

[angular-email-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-email-editor)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I was making a mistake that I passed the whole object contains `html`, `json` and `design` properties. Actually the method needs `design` property.

```
loadDesign() {
  console.log(this.data)
  this.emailEditor.loadDesign(this.data.design)
}
```